# Чтение из файла чисел размером около 2 гб

Tags: c++, filestream

Условие задачи таково, что сумма двух первых чисел может быть равна чуть меньше 2*(10^9), т.е. потребуется около 2 ГБ, а это больше ограничения в 16 МБ!!! Как обойти? Помогите решить.

Имя входного файла `in.txt`
Имя выходного файла стандартный вывод
Ограничение по памяти 16 мегабайт

В начале файла `in.txt` содержатся два целых числа. Если сложить их, то вы получите, позицию в файле,
начиная с которой находится третье число, которое вам нужно вывести.

Формат входных данных
Файл `in.txt`, сформированный по принципу, который описан выше. Гарантируется, что каждое из чисел целое и не превышает 10^9. Также гарантируется, что сумма первых двух чисел не будет отрицательным числом.

### Примеры

Входные данные:

`6 5 blah 25491`

Выходные данные:

`491`

Задача решена, спасибо Harry, вот правильный код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("in.txt", ios::in);
    int a, b, j = 0, pos1;

    //вывел два первых числа и сложил их
    infile >> a >> b;
    j = a+b;

    // потом, как Вы и сказали сдвинул
    infile.seekg(j, ios:: beg);
    infile >> pos1;
    cout << pos1;

    infile.close();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: а откуда предположение, что _сумма двух первых чисел может быть равна чуть меньше 2*(10^9)_?

Comment: "Гарантируется, что каждое из чисел целое и не превышает 10^9"

Comment: Ну так правильно не больше 1_000_000_000 - то есть 9 символов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да в чем проблема? Считываете первое число, для совсем уж гарантии отсутствия переполнений - в `long long int`, второе, находите смещение, пользуетесь [`seekg`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg), чтобы стать на нужное место в файле, читаете и выводите третье число...

Никаких проблем.

```
ifstream in("input.txt",ios::binary);
int pos1, pos2, num;
in >> pos1 >> pos2;
in.seekg(pos1+pos2);
in >> num;
cout << num;
```

Comment: 1 символ занимает 1 байт, 1 000 000 000 символов будет занимать 1гб. В условии ограничение по памяти в 16 мБ это в 100 раз меньше.

Comment: Откуда у вас столько символов? Вы что, хотите читать в память весь файл? :) Еще раз и внимательно перечитайте условие задачи.

Comment: ))))))))) Да, действительно, Вы правы это же всего лишь 9 символов, а не миллиард!!!

Comment: Всё замечательно получилось:

Comment: Ну, тогда помечайте ответ как принятый...

Comment: Помечаю, но он не увеличивает цифру, а просто выводит надпись, что прав мало, но мнение учтут.

Comment: Там птичка есть, ее надо нажать.